# Why the app is not on the App Store but it's on iTunes?

Tags: ipad, applications, ios-appstore, itunes-store, ios

This is really weird, my App Store is set to my country, Portugal and I checked on the iTunes browser using "pt" at URL, and the app I'm looking for it is listed there.

But when I search the app on the App Store in my iPad with iOS 10 it doesn't show up.

I'm not using any type of filter in the App Store, I'm just searching for the app.

By the way the app is AndroMoney.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More or less, yes. It means that the app is not tailored for the iPad, so you'll get the same user interface on the iPad as you would get on an iPhone.

You usually have the option of "zooming" it in and out, but even then it will not be as great as an app that is customized to take advantage of the iPad's screen size.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind.

My App Store was filtering apps only for iPad, and the App it's on "iPhone only"..

Does that mean, if I buy it and install the looks will be not so good?

Thank you!